# Prestashop 1.7: Differences between save and update?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In PS 17, are there any differences between the objects models `save` and `update` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save()` method calls `update()` if object already exists.

```
public function save($null_values = false, $auto_date = true)
{
    return (int) $this->id > 0 ? $this->update($null_values) : $this->add($auto_date, $null_values);
}
```

So you can call one or the other indistinctly if you know that the object exists.